# ¿Cómo implementar setInterval() correctamente?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

He realizado un código con el que se crea una tabla. Hasta ahora la actualizo con la meta `refresh`, pero me gustaría poder actualizarlo con `setInterval` o alguna función que repita la lectura de todo el código cada x tiempo.
He probado aplicar `setInterval` de diferentes maneras, pero no funciona y la tabla no se actualiza.
¿Cómo puedo implementar `setInterval()` correctamente para no tener que actualizar toda la página con la meta `refresh` y solo se actualice el código?

Código actual:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="odometer-theme-default.css" />
<script src="odometer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php

error_reporting(0);

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

$ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
$launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
return  $launch;
}

$text = file_get_contents("C:/topvs3.txt");

$exploded = multiexplode(array(" (","#1 ",") - #2 ",") - #3 ",") - #4 ",") - 
#5 ",") - #6 ",") - #7 ",") - #8 ",") - #9 ",") - #10 ",") - #11 ",") - #12 
",") - #13 ",") - #14 ",") - #15 ",") - #16 ",") - #17 ",") - #18 ",") - #19 
",") - #20 "),$text);
//var_dump($exploded);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$exploded1= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[1].txt");
$exploded2= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[3].txt");
$exploded3= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[5].txt");
$exploded4= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[7].txt");
$exploded5= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[9].txt");
$exploded6= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[11].txt");
$exploded7= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[13].txt");
$exploded8= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[15].txt");
$exploded9= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[17].txt");
$exploded10= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[19].txt");
$exploded11= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[21].txt");
$exploded12= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[23].txt");
$exploded13= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[25].txt");
$exploded14= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[27].txt");
$exploded15= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[29].txt");
$exploded16= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[31].txt");
$exploded17= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[33].txt");
$exploded18= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[35].txt");
$exploded19= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[37].txt");
$exploded20= file_get_contents("C:\Usuarios_txt/$exploded[39].txt");
$nombre1 = $exploded[1];
$nombre2 = $exploded[3];
$nombre3 = $exploded[5];
$nombre4 = $exploded[7];
$nombre5 = $exploded[9];
$nombre6 = $exploded[11];
$nombre7 = $exploded[13];
$nombre8 = $exploded[15];
$nombre9 = $exploded[17];
$nombre10 = $exploded[19];
$nombre11 = $exploded[21];
$nombre12 = $exploded[23];
$nombre13 = $exploded[25];
$nombre14 = $exploded[27];
$nombre15 = $exploded[29];
$nombre16 = $exploded[31];
$nombre17 = $exploded[33];
$nombre18 = $exploded[35];
$nombre19 = $exploded[37];
$nombre20 = $exploded[39];
$puntos1 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[2]);
$puntos2 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[4]);
$puntos3 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[6]);
$puntos4 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[8]);
$puntos5 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[10]);
$puntos6 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[12]);
$puntos7 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[14]);
$puntos8 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[16]);
$puntos9 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[18]);
$puntos10 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[20]);
$puntos11 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[22]);
$puntos12 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[24]);
$puntos13 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[26]);
$puntos14 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[28]);
$puntos15 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[30]);
$puntos16 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[32]);
$puntos17 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[34]);
$puntos18 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[36]);
$puntos19 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[38]);
$puntos20 = str_replace(".","",$exploded[40]);
$id1 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded1);
$id2 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded2);
$id3 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded3);
$id4 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded4);
$id5 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded5);
$id6 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded6);
$id7 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded7);
$id8 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded8);
$id9 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded9);
$id10 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded10);
$id11 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded11);
$id12 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded12);
$id13 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded13);
$id14 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded14);
$id15 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded15);
$id16 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded16);
$id17 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded17);
$id18 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded18);
$id19 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded19);
$id20 = multiexplode(array("|"),$exploded20);

ECHO <<<EOT
<div style='width: 900px; color: #c300f1; font-size: 28px; font- 
family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8;'>
<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>
<div style='display: inline; color: #FFFF00;'> 1.</div> $nombre1
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos1</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id1[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>
<div style='display: inline; color: #999999;'> 2.</div> $nombre2
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos2</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id2[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>
<div style='display: inline; color: #993300;'> 3.</div> $nombre3
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos3</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id3[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 4.</div> $nombre4
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos4</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id4[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 5.</div> $nombre5
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos5</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id5[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 6.</div> $nombre6
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos6</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id6[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 7.</div> $nombre7
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos7</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id7[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 8.</div> $nombre8
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos8</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id8[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 9.</div> $nombre9
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos9</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id9[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 10.</div> $nombre10
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos10</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id10[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 11.</div> $nombre11
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos11</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id11[0]</div></div>

 <div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, 
 sans-serif;'>
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 12.</div> $nombre12
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos12</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id12[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
 sans-serif;'>  
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 13.</div> $nombre13
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos13</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id13[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 14.</div> $nombre14
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos14</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id14[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 15.</div> $nombre15
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos15</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id15[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 16.</div> $nombre16
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos16</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id16[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 17.</div> $nombre17
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos17</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id17[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 18.</div> $nombre18
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos18</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id18[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 19.</div> $nombre19
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos19</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id19[0]</div></div>

<div align='center' style='color: #a4fe09; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, 
sans-serif;'>   
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> 20.</div> $nombre20
<div style='display: inline; color: #c300f1;'> | <div class='odometer' 
style='color: #fff;'>$puntos20</div> pts. | </div><div style='display: 
inline; color: #a4fe09;'>$id20[0]</div></div> 
</div>
EOT;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por adelantado.
Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo como lo estabas haciendo:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```

Con php:
asi

```
<?php 
header("Refresh: 30; URL='pagina.php'");
?>
```

o asi

```
setInterval("location.reload()",5000);
```

Con jquery:

```js
  //Cuando la página esté cargada completamente
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //Cada 10 segundos (10000 milisegundos) se ejecutará la función refrescar
    console.log("listo")
    setTimeout(refrescar, 10000);
  });
  function refrescar(){
    //Actualiza la página
    location.reload();
    console.log("refrescar")
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me funcionan el ejemplo de php (header) y la funcion jquery, pero el setInterval no me funciona. Dónde debe colocárse? Por otra banda más que refrescar la página, lo que quiero es qué  el código del body sea leído una vez tras otra cada x segundos. En mis tiempos se hacía con un goto, o algún tipo de bucle, pero en php no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: si lo que quieres es recargar la informacion puedes programar la funcion refrescar para que en vez de un location.reload() haga una peticion ajax y coja de nuevo los datos y luego tu los pintas de nuevo... para un archivo no se si ajax podra hacerlo ya que no lo he hecho nunca

Comment: Muchas gracias, probaré a ver.

Comment: Hola, bueno pues paso a dejar la solución ya que finalmente conseguí lo que buscaba. La solución es hacer un load de jquery. function(){
     $('#top').load('top.php');
    },2000    y llamar desde un div.  Gracias por las respuestas y saludos!